# Combining socket.io with Jquery : cant access $(this)

Tags: jquery, node.js, websocket, socket.io, async-await

So i'm using socket.io and jquery in a node project. I created the document ready function async because i have to await some functions in there.

```
$(async() =>{
  let socket = io();
  await some function
  $(document).on('event','object',async() =>{
    await some other function
    $(this).html('blablabla');
  }
}
```

Thing is that $(this) won't point to the object that trigger the event.I'm getting

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null
```

I searched a bit some other awnsers dont help me at all.Any idea how to access the object inside the event? Thanks.

Comment: Arrow functions don't bind this

Comment: Oh my god.. Never would have thought that. I just recently started using ES6 and i thought  that function(){} and ()=>{} are exactly the same. Thank to both of you.